# How many samples are needed to distinguish the means of two distributions in multi-armed bandits?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, mean, multiarmed-bandit

In a paper on Multi Armed Bandits, I came across the following statement:

> This generalizes the well-known fact that one needs of order $\frac{1}{\Delta^2}$ samples to differentiate the means of two distributions with gap $\Delta$.

(cf. [Audibert et al. (2010)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Remi_Munos/publication/221497549_Best_Arm_Identification_in_Multi-Armed_Bandits/links/09e41510be93d28d6c000000/Best-Arm-Identification-in-Multi-Armed-Bandits.pdf) )

To me, this is not "well known". That is why I would appreciate a hint where this "fact" comes from.
In Multi Armed Bandits, a common assumption is that the random variables are bounded between 0 and 1. However, the exact distribution is not known.

Answer (score 5):

This "*well-known*" fact comes from the fact that the lower bound on the sample complexity (i.e. the number of samples needed to differentiate the means of two arms) is proportional to $1/\Delta^2$.

**You can actually say more**: any algorithm, in order to identify with probability at least $1-\delta$ the best arm (i.e. the one having the largest mean) between two distributions, needs a number of samples $\tau$ that satisfy

$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau] \gtrsim 1/\Delta^2\log(1/\delta),
$$

and this comes from a popular [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v49/garivier16a.pdf) in the bandit literature. See the end of page 6 for the inverse gap argument.